# Why are these C++ Commands looked down upon?

Tags: c++, iostream, iomanip

I know many people have suggested to me to not use code such as

```
using namespace std;
```

or

```
system ("pause");
system ("cls");
system ("color f0");//and other system commands
```

or

```
goto TitleScreen;
goto DeathScreen;
```

or

```
break;
```

and I'm just wondering why these things are looked down upon and what C++ commands can replace the bad habits of mine?

Comment: So you really don't know why `goto` is looked down upon?  Ever hear of spaghetti code?

Comment: Most of those are looked down on, and usually for good reasons, but what makes you think that `break` is? It is not.

Comment: I am not sure who said `break` but it is definitely used in a lot of cases, such as `switch`. For `goto`, in almost most cases, you will not need to use it, if you design your code properly. To me `goto` decreases the readability of the code.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/292/ :)

Comment: @macroland `goto` also decreases your chances of someone looking at your code if you have a bug.  At least for me, if I see `goto`, I don't look at the code any further, unless I *have* to.

Comment: There are appropriate uses of all of these, including `goto`.  (state machine implementations, for example, are often done using `goto`s)

Comment: There is no guarantee that the operating system your program is running on has a "pause" command.  Also, you can't guarantee the platform has a screen.  Some platforms run programs in a "command window", which may not be cleared.  Some platforms that support terminals, may not support color terminals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, let's go one-by-one. I will be posting links to great post by some other people, there's no points reinventing the wheel, and they've done a pretty good job.

```
using namespace std;
```

[Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/)

```
system ("pause");
system ("cls");
system ("color f0");//and other system commands
```

[Why system() is evil](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/)

```
break;
```

There's nothing necessarily bad about break if used in moderation. Too many breaks in a for loop might suggest your logic is getting a bit too complex, and may be factored out, but in general most 'dangers' with `break` and `continue` can be alleviated by writing clear code.